# Getting java.lang.SecurityException: attempted to open sandboxed jar as a Trusted-Library

Tags: java, security, jar, applet, jarsigner

After upgrading to latest java version v1.7.0.51 I am getting:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: attempted to open sandboxed jar as a Trusted-Library
```

I have added the following attributes in the manifest file of my jar which is causing the issue. After adding these attributes, I am signing the jar file and using it.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Trusted-Library: true
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
Permissions: sandbox
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
Codebase: *
```

I tried other combinations also like "Permissions: all-permissions", "Trusted-Library: false", etc but nothing worked out. Any advice is appreciable.

Comment: I don't think there would be any point in having a sandboxed **trusted** library.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error and I also specify "Permissions: sandbox" in jar file.
Finally, the problem is fixed by remove "Trusted-Library: true".